# Speed up Update statement T-SQL with Top 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I'm creating a stored procedure for an ETL script that'll run once per hour to give results of specific operations to users.

I need to find the previous result to the current result. This is fine and I have a working query that I export into Excel. However now I wish to automate the process.

The stored procedure averages at 42 seconds per run. This isn't feasible when running once an hour on the server as I have other automated scripts also running.

My issue is one chunk of the stored procedure averages at 28 seconds, whilst everything else usually takes less than a second (shows up at 00:00:00 in SSMS).

I've managed to reduce the runtime of other chunks myself bringing it down to 42 seconds average, but I can't do this.

I was wondering if any of you know any specfic ways to speed this small chunk up?

```
UPDATE #tmp
SET prev_test_date = (  
    SELECT TOP 1 r.test_date 
    FROM [dbo].[results] r (NOLOCK)
    WHERE r.number = #tmp.number
    AND r.test_date < #tmp.test_date
    ORDER BY r.test_date DESC
)
```

I was originally going to use joins for this to speed it up, although I can't do this due to the TOP 1 part of the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a feeling you tossed that NOLOCK hint in there to "speed things up". That query hint is not a magic go faster button. It has some very serious side effects. You need to fully understand that hint before using it. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I added it as we don't mind getting dirty results and it'd speed it up.

Comment: It is far more than dirty reads. You really should read that article before you splatter that hint all over the place. There are time it is appropriate and this may be one of them but so many people think it is just dirty reads.

Comment: Post the query plan and all the detail on why you need it to run faster is not necessary.

Comment: Can you give more detail on the structure of Results table, and of #tmp? What are the unique keys of each of those tables? How many rows in each?

Comment: We have an ID which would be the unique key. Although, this is a warehouse transaction table so we need to use the number (renamed as policy says I can't share column names), to get all records. As I'm doing a historical query I'm using a combination of the number and the test_date to find the current (latest) result and the result just before the latest.

Comment: Paul what is wrong with lag.  If you have 2012 what happened to lag?

Comment: The lag didn't find the date_of_test directly before the current test.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
UPDATE #tmp
SET prev_test_date = (  
    SELECT TOP 1 r.test_date 
    FROM [dbo].[results] r
    WHERE r.number = #tmp.number AND
          r.test_date < #tmp.test_date
    ORDER BY r.test_date DESC
)
```

You want an index on `r(number, test_date)`.

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ and the test dates are not duplicated, you can also write this as:

```
with r as (
      select r.*,
             lag(r.test_date) over (partition by r.number order by r.test_date desc) as prev_test_date
      from [dbo].[results] r
     )
update t
    set t.prev_test_date = r.prev_test_date
    from #tmp t join
         r
         on t.number = r.number;
```

In fact, if this is the case, you might not need the temporary table.  You might be able to modify the code just to use `lag()`.

Comment: What does the lag() do?

Comment: Hi sorry, I'm on SQL Server 2012. This only applies to Azure, 2014 and 2016.

Comment: Update: Indexing did not speed up the update statement.

Comment: What do you mean not available on 2012?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I can't take everything from the results table as there is millions of rows in this table. Would it work if I added some constraints here?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE #tmp
   SET #tmp.prev_test_date = tt.maxdate 
from #tmp 
join 
(
select #tmp.number, max(r.test_date) maxdate 
  from #tmp
  join [dbo].[results] r (NOLOCK)
        on r.number = #tmp.number
       AND r.test_date < #tmp.test_date
 group by #tmp.number 
 ) tt
 on tt.number = #tmp.number
```

and have indexes on both #tmp and [results] on number, text_date

Comment: Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Paul Yes I forgot about that.  Need to have a subquery.  I will fix it or delete it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE #tmp
SET prev_test_date = (  
    SELECT max(r.test_date) 
    FROM [dbo].[results] r (NOLOCK)
    WHERE r.number = #tmp.number
    AND r.test_date < #tmp.test_date    
)
```

Without more info it is hard to tell, but if there is simply too much processing You may need to make separate precalculated table and update it incrementally on data change.

Comment: Not sure if this will be faster but it is sure worth a try

Comment: This solution takes the same amount of process time as the original. Sorry. D:

Comment: Ok, I did not even expect speed up, it aimed the "I can't do this due to the TOP 1 part of the query" issue - now there is no TOP 1 part. Tested on table with 16M rows and 300k unique "numbers", this query takes about 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having to make some assumptions about the structure and contents of your tables, but if my assumptions are correct, here's the approach I usually use in such situations:

```
with cteOrderedResults as (
  -- Ideally R will be clustered by number, test_date for this
  select      R.number
              ,R.test_date
              ,row_number() over  (   partition by R.number
                                      order by R.test_date desc 
                                      -- So the most recent R.test_date from 
                                      -- before T.test_date gets RowNo=1
                                  ) as RowNo
  from        dbo.results R
  inner join  #tmp T            on R.number=T.number
                                and R.test_date<T.test_date

  )
update      T
set         T.prev_test_date=R.test_date
from        #tmp T
inner join  cteOrderedResults R   on T.number=R.number
                                  and 1=R.RowNo
```

This approach works quickly for me on rowsets ranging up to about the million mark. As I've commented, I believe the partitioned row_number() is going to be taking advantage of a corresponding clustered index if it exists; you might find this doesn't work so fast if you don't have the table clustered appropriately.

I agree with comments made elsewhere here, that you should only add the `nolock` hint back in if you're really sure you need it. If you do, you should use the full correct syntax, `with (nolock)`. From the [official MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187373.aspx):

> Omitting the WITH keyword is a deprecated feature: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.